# Exclude slf4j folder, while building maven jar-with-dependency

Tags: maven, build, maven-plugin, slf4j, maven-assembly-plugin

I am trying to exclude slf4j folder from jar while building using "maven-assembly-plugin". I tried to use exclued folder but that is not helping. The following is my POM file.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<artifactId>executor</artifactId>
<name>executor</name>
<description>Executor</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>access</groupId>
    <artifactId>access-parent</artifactId>
    <version>${my.version}</version>
    <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.jmockit</groupId>
        <artifactId>jmockit</artifactId>
        <version>${jmockit.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JaCoCo runtime must be in classpath for offline mode -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.jacoco.agent</artifactId>
        <classifier>runtime</classifier>
        <version>${jacoco.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.oozie</groupId>
        <artifactId>oozie-client</artifactId>
        <version>${oozie.client.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>${mysql.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.storm</groupId>
        <artifactId>storm-core</artifactId>
        <version>${storm.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.storm</groupId>
        <artifactId>storm-kafka</artifactId>
        <version>${storm.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>${kafka.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.zookeeper</groupId>
                <artifactId>zookeeper</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.zookeeper</groupId>
        <artifactId>zookeeper</artifactId>
        <version>${zookeeper.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.janino</groupId>
        <artifactId>janino</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.8</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Configuration related dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Cache related dependency -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>${guava.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Testing dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
        <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
        <version>${mockito.core.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
        <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito</artifactId>
        <version>${powermock.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
        <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
        <version>${powermock.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>jdk.tools</groupId>
        <artifactId>jdk.tools</artifactId>
        <version>${java.version}</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${java.home}/../lib/tools.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <artifactId>commons</artifactId>
        <groupId>access</groupId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-validator</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-validator</artifactId>
        <version>${commons.validator.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <artifactId>service</artifactId>
        <groupId>aggregate</groupId>
        <version>${service.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
        <artifactId>hive-metastore</artifactId>
        <version>${hive-metastore.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
        <artifactId>hive-common</artifactId>
        <version>${hive-common.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.thrift</groupId>
        <artifactId>libthrift</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <resources>
    <resource>
        <directory>../commons/src/main/resources</directory>
        <excludes>
            <exclude>config.properties</exclude>
            <exclude>hibernate.cfg.xml</exclude>
            <exclude>Metadata DDL.txt</exclude>
        </excludes>
    </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>

        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>

                    <id>execution1</id>
                    <configuration>

                        <descriptorRefs>
                            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                        </descriptorRefs>
                        <archive>
                            <manifest>
                                <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                                <mainClass>my.main.class.Topology</mainClass>
                            </manifest>
                            <manifestEntries>
                                <Class-Path>conf/</Class-Path>
                            </manifestEntries>
                        </archive>
                    </configuration>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>execution2</id>
                    <configuration>
                        <descriptors>
                            <descriptor>src/main/resources/assembly.xml</descriptor>
                        </descriptors>
                    </configuration>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>

            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${jacoco.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>instrument</id>
                    <phase>process-classes</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>instrument</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>restore</id>
                    <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>restore-instrumented-classes</goal>
                        <goal>report</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>


        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.19.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <systemPropertyVariables>
                    <!-- JaCoCo runtime must know where to dump coverage: -->
                    <jacoco-agent.destfile>target/jacoco.exec</jacoco-agent.destfile>
                </systemPropertyVariables>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>


</build>

    <profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>local</id>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.storm</groupId>
                <artifactId>storm-core</artifactId>
                <version>0.9.5</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.6</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <descriptorRefs>
                            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                        </descriptorRefs>
                        <finalName>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}-local</finalName>
                        <archive>
                            <manifest>
                                <mainClass>my.main.classTopology</mainClass>
                            </manifest>
                        </archive>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>make-assembly</id>
                            <phase>package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>single</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

I need to exclude the slf4j folder. whenever i build the project, I can find the folder in .jar/org/slf4j directory.Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by 'folder'? What is happening that you don't want?

Comment: When the "executor-1.1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar" get created, inside the jar we get directory "org/slf4j". when I submit this jar without deleting the directory "slf4j". The service runs without any error, but when I submit this jar without deleting "slf4j" directory, the service fails to run. So i need to delete "slf4j" directory.

Comment: you will need to change the scope of the slf4j dependencies to be 'provided' and then, I believe, the assembly plugin will leave them out.